# Is there a need of network additional security measure

Tags: security, network, ethereum-design, firewalls, networking

I didn't find information about the risk and threat of being connected to the Ethereum network / internet. I was wondering if we would need additional measures such as a firewall, proxy to protect some intrusion inside a corporate network.

Edit:

I am trying to understand what are the risks to have a machine connected to the etheureum network inside a corporate network.
Are there some risks that an attacker could gain access to the internal network.
If so, what kind of threat is it.

If you can clarify how the Ethereum network is connected to the internet so that I could better understand how malicious activities could take place.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough details on your use case to be answerable.

But generally yes, it makes sense to have a firewall.

Comment: I am trying to understand what are the risks to have a machine connected to the etheureum network inside a corporate network.
Are there some risks that an attacker could gain access to the internal network.
If so, what kind of threat is it.